# cx_Oracle: Error 933. ORA-00933: "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to run the following query with cx_Oracle:

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4
FROM AF.AF_ENCA
WHERE FIELD1 >= to_date('1986-09-23 16:18:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss')
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

This is my Python code, in case it makes any difference:

```
query_str = "SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4 FROM AF.AF_ENCA WHERE FIELD1 >= to_date('1986-09-23 16:18:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss')"
try:
    cursor.execute(query_str)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, exc:
    error, = exc
    print ("Error code: %s. Message: %s" % (error.code, error.message))
```

I have revised my query but I can't see what's wrong with it. Any help?

Comment: looks OK to me. What if you run the same query through sqlplus command line?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the sqlplus command line.

Comment: Should the query end in a semicolon? Also, could you replace the query with `select sysdate from dual` and test?